# Properties of Finite maps on hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Please have a look at page 49-50(Hypersurfaces; finite and quasi-finite
maps) of J.S. Milne's Algebraic Geometry notes  http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ag.html. I have two queries:

1. Consider the definition of the finite map at the beginning of page 50. When $\varphi$ is finite, is$\varphi^{*}:k[V]\rightarrow k[W]$ the structural homomorphism of the algebras? In that case $k[W]=\varphi^{*}(k[V])[x_{1},\ldots,x_{m}]$ for some $m$ and $k[W]$ is integral over $\varphi^{*}(k[V])$?
2. Just before proposition 2.40 we have the statement: The projection map $H\rightarrow A^{n}$(defined at the beginning of page 49) is finite $\iff$ $a_{0}$ is nonzero constant. I would really appreciate a detailed proof of this fact as I'm having a hard time understanding finite maps.

Thanks in advance!!